# What Can A Java Package Be Compared To In .NET?

Tags: java, naming-conventions, package

I've been working with .NET for a number of years, but recently I've been confronted with a simple project in Java.  The syntax was easy enough to learn - pretty straight forward and common.  The thing that confused me most, however, was the project structure.

In .NET I'm very accustom to classes to contain my different things, however, `Packages` confuse me.  They seem almost like .NET namespaces except that they actually affect the project directory layout.

Not only that, the naming convention was absolutely forign to me.  I was told to name the package using the company site in reverse with the application name at the end (e.g. `com.company.www.applicationname`).  Not only that, I was also told to name the main class the name of the application. It seems redundant almost now (class name, package name, and project name).

So what is all of this about?  What could I compare these packages to in .NET and how can I wrap my head around them? *- and whats with the naming conventions?*

Comment: The name of a class with a main function has no effect. It sounds like a convention of your organization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`packages` in Java are a way to make it so that different libraries can re-use class names without conflicting with each other. Packages are like another scope rule that the language provides. For example:

```
public class Example {
    String exampleString = "example";
}

public class Another {
    String exampleString = "This would never work with a global name space";
}
```

We are able to have two `String` objects with the `exampleString` identifier in the same program because they are in a different `scope`. Similarly,

```
package example;
public class Example { }
```

and in a separate file

```
package separateexample;
public class Example {}
```

We can have a class name with the same name, because it is a different scope. We can still uniquely specify the object:

`example.Example` or `separaeteexample.Example`
These are the fully qualified class names of these classes.

For more information check out [the java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html)

As for the convention for Java packages: if you want to write a library and have many people use it, you need to make sure there are no naming conflicts. Packages can be used like above to avoid them - but in order to make sure nothing will conflict, such as the package name itself, you would need a completely globally unique package name that you can make sure no other company will be using while trying to use your product. Domain names happen to be globally unique strings, so it is convention to use your companies domain name as a package name, reversed.

```
com.example.myapp.Example
```

could never conflict so long as you really own example.com (and nobody breaks the convention)

So to answer your main question `packages` in Java are the same concept as `namespaces` in .Net